# Orchard CMS Recent Blog Post Widget Alternate View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard CMS and MVC so please forgive my ignorance. I've done a search and not found anything apparently relevant....

In one of the Footer Quad zone on my Orchard site I want to show the 5 most recent blog posts, just by title. At present it show the title, post, tags etc all in their unformatted state(Ive not style the blog yet).

Using the tracing tool I've created an alternate view called;

```
Parts.Blogs.RecentBlogPosts
```

However the only content in this view is;

```
@Display(Model.ContentItems)
```

Which -unlike other installed widgets Ive edited alternate views for- doesn't give me anything to play around with to create the layout I'm needing to create.

Have I selected the wrong shape / view, or do I need to get stuck in with some coding???

As I say, I'm new to both MVC and Orchard but very keen to learn. Any help on this will, as always, be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does deserve an explanation. Model.ContentItems here really is a List shape. When you call Display with it, it will locate the most appropriate template for a list shape (and that can be an alternate) and renders it. The default List rendering just renders UL/LI and in each LI calls Display on the individual Content shape for the list element, but with the Summary display type. When that in turn gets rendered, the system locates the most relevant Content template, which usually renders a bunch of zones, inside of which the parts get pushed according to placement. So there is a lot going on, in quite a few nested levels.
Still, it is possible to override the whole thing at any level. The difficulty is to know what to put there. The easiest for this is to explore the Model in shape tracing and see what you can use.
This article shows how to override list rendering in a particular situation and take it over entirely:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx

Comment: Ah! The great Bertrand. I'm honoured to have your assistance. From my short time with Orchard I've seen you are clearly the man in the know. ;-)

Comment: O_o You're too kind. Real question is, does this help?

Comment: Yes, Ive managed to quickly turn your sample into the layout I need. Unfortunately its late, so ive not really looked at the code itself, or your excellent explanation yet. However, I will do this tomorrow without a doubt. Im very keen to understand what is going on, inorder that I can learn more. Thanks for the assistance, and spending so much time and effort(generally) to explain how Orchard works.

Comment: How would I go about doing the same sort of thing but with the blog summary page and then the actual blog post page. Again, all I can seem to find is individual zone elements. This leaves me in a similar situation, in that I need to re-arrange things and make alterations that require me to have control of the top level shape so to speak. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated @Bertrand Le Roy

Comment: The standard way of moving shapes around is placement. If you don't want to use placement for whatever reason, read this: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/31/so-you-don-t-want-to-use-placement-info.aspx

Comment: I'd like to add images and restyle some of the elements. I wondered if there was a similar method as that described for the original question but for the blog summary page?

Comment: Not following. What's not working with the previously made suggestions?

Comment: Just wondered if there was a way to override this whole element in a similar way as to how you showed me for the blog widget? For the greater level of control that apparently gives. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Sure: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2012/07/01/my-body-summary-template-for-orchard.aspx

Comment: Ive popped that in my theme>Views>Parts but it doesnt appear to be kicking in at all. Any ideas, what Im missing / doing wrong??? dev.codecurators.co.uk/explore-our-thinking Thanks Bertrand I appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't know, you're not giving a lot of information. It works on my machine ;) Is your theme enabled? Do other overrides work? Are you sure you have the right file name?

Comment: Sorry. Ive followed the blog post you directed me to. Created the required file with just the code described on your blog tutorial. Place it in the theme and in the parts folder. But nothing changes. Other overrides such as the one you previously identified, and my own override of the twitter widget all workfine.

Comment: In the same theme? Did you verify in shape tracing what were the possible alternates?

Answer (score 3):

I got the exact same problem while trying to differentiate recent blog posts layout from blog summary posts. I followed this concept

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/31/so-you-don-t-want-to-use-placement-info.aspx

and created Parts.Blogs.RecentBlogPosts alternate. Then while navigating through the model using shape tracing tool I found all elements I was looking for and put them in my new shape. I know that my approach might not be the most appropriate one but it works. Maybe it would be a starting point for someone who would need to do similar thing:

```
<div class="last-news">
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.ContentItems.ContentItems.Items)
{
    var max = (item.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text.Length > 100) ? 100 : item.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text.Length;

    <li><header>@Display(item.ContentItem.CommonPart.PublishedUtc.ToShortDateString())</header></li>
    <li><h1><a href="/@item.ContentItem.Parts[5].Path">@Display(item.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title)</a></h1></li>
    <li>@Display(Html.Raw(item.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text.Substring(0, max)))</li>
}
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Parts.Blogs.RecentBlogPosts` view displays `Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List` shape (`Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List.cshtml`) which displays BlogPost content items. (You can see it in RecentBlogPostsPartDriver.cs). BlogPost content type consists of TitlePart and BodyPart parts which has their own shapes and views (or templates in Orchard terminology).
So to make some corrections for those templates you could try to alternate `Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List`, `Parts_Common_Body_Summary` and other shapes.

Please see the following instructions on [Orchard docs page](http://docs.orchardproject.net/) especially:

1. Alternates
2. Accessing and Rendering Shapes

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Im still none the wiser. I was able to create an alternate for the twitter widget quite easily. But this really isnt making any sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, well I think Im getting somewhere. But based on the route Im currently taking, to get only Titles in the feed, I will have to create empty alternates for all the other parts. This just seems a bit wrong.

Comment: You can hide summary of blog posts by adding to your _placement.info_ file the following: `<Place Parts_Common_Body_Summary="-"/>`. This will remove the shape from showing for any time when your module/theme is on.

Comment: But that would also remove it from the blog summary page?? I only want to remove these from the widget Ive got placed in the footer of every page. My aim is to have this widget showing the titles of the most recent 3 or 4 blog posts.